# SQL Server visual basic .net connection string

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

Please explain the following Visual Basic .net command :

```
newStr = "Data Source=xxxxxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxxxxx;User ID=;Password="
```

What is `Data Source`? What is `Initial Catalog`?

My SQL Server database name is `Mainbazneshast`, my table name is `Shakhsi`.

Comment: Check this site : [connectionstrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/connection-strings-explained/) ;).

Answer (score 0):

"Data Source" is most important things for connecting the database

Data Source means which computer or server has your database.
if the database server and application in same server and SQL server Full edition

---

Data Source = (local) or . or (SQLSERVER) ||note:Default instance)

Either Data Source is your computer IP address 
Data Source = your computer id address ( Note: Data Source=192.168.1.12)

---

Initial Catalog  is your database name
Initial Catalog=Mainbazneshast

---

Table name do not need for database connection.